# Displaying text when mouseover a list image

Tags: html, css, web, html-lists

I am generating a list of images that scrolls horizontally on a page using:
https://jsfiddle.net/9oLLv1op/3/

```
<ul class="images">
    <a href="images/Pumpkins01.png" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/Pumpkins01.png" alt="" width="300" height="400">
</a></li></ul>
```

When I mouse over each image I need it to display a different body of text in a different div space below the image list. 
Would it be better to use css and div wrappers to do this? im pretty lost.
I have found ways to do this without the use of an unordered list but can not figure it out this way.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I need a different body of text to be displayed for each image and the last element to be hovered over will have its text remain in the "show-me" div when the user mouses off.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to place the div with text? Could you please update your fiddle with it?

Comment: If you want to have one element (e.g. div) and just change the text inside it when user hover over the image, then JavaScript will be needed.

Comment: I need a different body of text to be displayed for each image and the last element to be hovered over will have its text remain in the "show-me" div when the user mouses off., i've updated the code - the div is just below the images and will be formatted later.

Comment: Please check my answer and fiddle, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Fu.. I forgot to update the fiddle, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/Pawel256/whfar56x/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery (can be done in pure JS): https://jsfiddle.net/Pawel256/whfar56x/2/

1.Add a div in with you want to display the description for the images

2.Add mouseover and change the text inside the description div:

```
$(".image1").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#show-me").text('1. This is image1 description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');
});
```

3.Remember to add mouseleave and clear the description div

```
$(".image1, .image2, .image3").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#show-me").text('');
});
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you for the quick and informative lesson i very much appreciate it and wish you well - im quite new to all of this and just doing it for fun to create a portfolio website mock up - do you think this would be better if i used pure css instead of ordered and unordered lists?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript, and CSS are two possible approaches.

JavaScript: Add a on hover event listener to the images, that sets the display value of the corresponding div. ('none' for invisible, 'block' for visible)

CSS: I think that this approach would look cooler, although it would deviate from the original question. I would create divs that occupy the same space as the image, and set them to be visible on hover. (display:none; divs don't have a ':hover' puesdo-class. use transparency instead).